# grails - how create new session for different browser tabs

Tags: session, grails

I'm trying to create simple web-app using grails.

Now, I need create new session when user opens same page in different tabs to avoid displaying same data in all opened tabs.

is it possible to define that page was opened in new tab? if it possible how create new session in controller action?.

or maybe there is a way to get something like browser tab-id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how a session works and they are assigned.

A session is per browser (and domain/host).

So, even though you can create a new session in a controller action it won't help because that will become the session for all the tabs of the browser and the previous session(s) will be invalidated/abandoned.

There is no such thing as a browser tab id.

You'll need to address the root issue which is causing your data affinity to be based on a browser session. Make it based on something else. (Just a general suggestion since this isn't part of your questions and you haven't provided any details.)

Comment: In my case, when user click a button, part of data generated and if we open another tab the data will be there, but I need somehow idintify that it's another tab and not display data that were previuosli load. I thought than session could help me but I wrong. So, I think additional url parameter may help, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thoughts on this.

What you are trying to accomplish may appear simple but you will need some mechanism to capture who each session be whether it be a spring security username or actual http session id and to then store with that what controller actions they have visited so far and to keep this consistently updated whilst checking it over and over again. 
Something as simple as

```
[
['10001':[controller:'someController', 'someAction'],[controller:'someController1', 'someAction1'],
],
['10002':[controller:'someController', 'someAction'],[controller:'someController1', 'someAction1']
]
```

Where '10001' is your key of your map and is your session id then it contains a list of internal maps of places visited that you capture and try to work out if they been there already - basically the question here is....

Where is the AI to say if they have seen someAction1 they should see action2 and what happens when they seen  action1 and action2 and so on an ever ending loop of and what next ?

Either way you could do all that as a session variable that contains a map like above - the issue you will hit will be concurrent map (where it gets updated and read at the same time).
So you will then need to look over and into using  concurrent hashmaps to get around such issues.

Either way the problem with all of above is the consistent logic to figure out if they have seen all possible options then what next ?

I think you are far better off thinking of it from a different point of view as in base it on timestamp and move the query or whatever it is to randomly generate a different output based on that timestamp since that is always going to change regardless of the user

Comment: it could actually be an increment that is stored for each session id so session.visited=(session.visited?:0)+1 upon each hit of the controller where you then change render view="index${session.visited}" and that then opens index0.gsp index1.gsp index2.gsp and so on and the increment either above and pages start from 1 or below pages start from 0 as a basic example